# Godot, one large background image vs tilemap?

Tags: game-development, godot, tile

Good evening all! I am working on a metroidvania-like project and have been playing around with level design in both Godot and Tiled.  I have found a few ways to design my levels and it has me very curious about the impacts of both.

For starters, rather than having a million tiles with their own collisions, I have left them out of the tiles and instead just been using static bodies with collision shapes.  That brings me from several hundred smaller collision shapes to maybe 20-30 on larger maps.  That said, I have run into the issue where I can either have my level as a tile map, or a larger image exported from Tiled.

What are the downsides to using a larger static image as my world vs tiling it?  Is one specifically better with performance than the other? If it matters, each "screen" is it's own scene, so it's not like there's a ton going on.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do it both ways. If the levels aren't huge you also shouldn't see much differences when it comes to performance (although I never really tested it).

In my view, the benefit of using Godot's Tilemaps is that your level design can be adjusted more easily. If you want to slightly modify something later on, you wouldn't have to bother with adjusting each and every collision shape that might have been affected by the changes.
E.g. if you'd move a platform using a background image as level, you'd have to make sure your overlayed static body is aligned with the moved platform again. That doesn't sound like a big deal but could become very cumbersome during play testing.

The same is true for stuff like navigation or occlusion shapes, which are very nicely integrated in Godot's tilemaps.

Additionally, using a single image as background you couldn't modify tiles by code. For example, if you want to open a door on the map you'd either need to reload the whole image or place the doors as individual nodes on the map.
Using Godot's tilemap you could write a little script that keeps track of interactive tiles and replaces them if needed.

Nonetheless, after all it comes down to personal preference and as I said, you can do it either way.